# Retain the State of Partial view when Tab Changes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery Tab , in Tab 2 i designed a Search Page which does Dynamic search on 8 fields and display the result on a Grid, i am making use of Partial view to design the Tab 2 design. 
The issue i have is when i shift from one tab to other tab i am losing my search result .
Can some body help me here

In SearchContract Tab i can search a contract by number,date,department etc and the search result i am displaying in the same Partial view using a fixheadtable grid..

Once i select my search Criteria and make a search the results get displayed in the grid. But once i a tab out and come back to the same tab  i loose my grid result as well as search criteria

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#HrTabStripContainer").tabs({
        create: OnCreateDefaultTabHandler,
        beforeActivate: BeforeActivateTabHandler,
        cache:true,
        active: 0,
        disabled : [2]

});
OnCreateDefaultTabHandler = function () {
        LoadNewContract();
        LoadSearchContract();
    //disable others
}
BeforeActivateTabHandler = function (event, ui) {
    switch ($(ui.newTab).index()) {
        case 0:
            LoadNewContract()
            break;
        case 1:
            LoadSearchContract();
            break;
        case 2:
            LoadEditContract();
            break;
        default:
            //ToDo: Log error...low priority
    }
}

var LoadSearchContract = function () {
    $("#HrTabStripContainer").tabs({ disabled: [2] });
    $("#_SearchContract").load("Contracts/_SearchContract");

};
```

In Controller I am using

[HttpGet]

```
   public ActionResult _SearchContract()
   {
       var model = new SearchContractModel();
       model.SelPayRec = null;
       model.srchPayRec = ViewDataTasks.GetPayableReceivable();
       model.srchCntrctType = ViewDataTasks.GetContractTypes();
       model.srchCntrctStatus = ViewDataTasks.getContractStatus();
       return PartialView(model);
   }
```

in Partial View I am using

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
    $("#contractNumber").val("");
    var btnFindContract = $("#btnFindContract");
    fixedTblFindEmployee();
    // tblScrollFindEmployee();
    btnFindContract.on("click", (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#findCntrctTable tbody").empty();          
        searchContract();          

    }));


    function searchContract() {          
        var searchCriteria = {
            ContractNBR: $("#srchCntrctNbr").val(),
            RequestingOfficeDistrict: $("#srchofficeDist").val(),
            Contractor: $("#srchCntrctr").val(),
            SPNBR: $("#SP").val(),
            Contract_Stat: $("#srchCntrctStatus option:selected").text(),
            ContractType: $("#srchCntrctType option:selected").text(),
            PayableReceivable: $("#srchPayRec option:selected").text(),
            FromDate: $('#srchReqStrtDt').val(),
            ToDate: $('#srchReqEndDt').val(),
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "Contracts/LoadContractList",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'searchCriteria': JSON.stringify(searchCriteria) },
            cache: false
        }).done(function (data, e) {
            writetable(data);
        });

    };


    function writetable(data) {         
        var tableOutline = '';          
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var id = 'row' + data[i].ContractNumber;
            tableOutline = tableOutline + '<tr id="row_' + data[i].ContractNumber + '" onclick="getCntrctNbr(this,' + data[i].ContractNumber + ')"><td><a>';
            tableOutline = tableOutline + data[i].ContractNumber + '</a></td><td>' + data[i].RequestorName + '</td><td>' + data[i].RequestingOffDisct + '</td><td>' + formatJSONDate(data[i].RequestedDate) + '</td><td>' + data[i].ContractStatus + '</td><td>' + formatCurrency(data[i].EstimateContractCost) + '</td><td>' + data[i].ContractType + '</td><td>' + data[i].PayReceivable + '</td></tr>';
        }
            tableOutline = tableOutline;
            $('#findCntrctTable').append(tableOutline);
            $('#findCntrctTable').show();
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "losing my search result". What are these results? Where are the results -- Are the results on a specific tab or on an element separate from the tab widget? What happens in your `Contracts/_SearchContract` action? What happens on the other tabs? What version of jQueryUI are you using? You are possibly using [deprecated API](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event).

Comment: You reload from server each time you switch tabs `$("#_SearchContract").load("Contracts/_SearchContract");` so your content will reset.

Comment: but i am already doing in LoadSearchContract function during OnCreateDefaultTabHandler and also during BeforeActiveTabHandler

Comment: Right, it reloads the page which is what you don't want to happen.

Comment: Once it reloads i loosing all the data that which i had search for. i need to retain the value.

Comment: You probably don't want to load your tab content with `.load()` like you are now. What might work better is if you add the forms to each tab on one page and not use the `beforeActivate` event to load content. If these forms are dynamic and you feel you must use `.load()` you'll need to flag conditions if the page has already been loaded once.

Comment: I am kind of newbie here, can you please elobrate how i can achieve

Comment: how to and where i can put the condition

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve the issue, i put the check it is working now